# Adding project dependency to web project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, war

I have a Dynamic Web Project that gets deployed as a WAR that I have created in Eclipse. The project depends on 2 other small projects. I have them marked for export, and have them on the build path, but Eclipse warns me that it will not be exported, and sure enough, I get a ClassNotFoundException when I try to compile.

If need be, I can pull all the java files into a .zip file, but I don't know how to add a .zip file as a dependency. I'm sure I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the web project's Properties dialog (context menu, or Project menu from the menu bar) and go to the `Deployment Assembly` page. This is where you tell it to also make them jars when deploying.